# Generation of array incorrect in typescript

Tags: typescript

I need to generate an array based on the given minimum and maximum number. It should be equally divided into 7 parts. I am trying this in my typescript code

Here is the code that I have written. Could you let me know what is going wrong

```
 private generate1YAxisArray(min: any, max: any) {
    let count = 7;
    for (let i = min; i <= max;  i = count) {
      this.yAxisData.push(count);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 private generate1YAxisArray(min: any, max: any) {
     let count = 7;
     for (let i = min; i <= max;  i++) {
         this.yAxisData.push(count);
     }
 }
```

Whats the purpose of count?

Comment: i am basically trying to compute the yxis for the high chart graph. So for e.g   min: 90000 and    max: 110000 , the numbers should be equally divided in 7 points. It could be 90,000, 95,000  so on

Comment: how should they be divided? Where should they be put in?

Comment: I dont want difference of 7 numbers. What I want is whatever is minimum and maximum number they should be equally divided and have minimum 7 equal points. Need to generate an array accordingly